# SQL instead of insert trigger confusion

Tags: sql, sql-server

So i was watching a youtube tutorial [Instead of insert trigger Part 45](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MseKoztMpoo&list=PL08903FB7ACA1C2FB&index=45) (if someone is interested) about **instead of triggers**.

The guy there was trying to insert values into a view, which is impossible of course. So he made an instead of trigger and he used the inserted table, to insert the values into the tables the view is made of, long story.

My point is, how did he use the inserted table when there wasn't actually anything inserted?

I mean you get an error than you can't insert into the view. Doesn't the inserted table contain data that has only actually been inserted somewhere?

Comment: An Instead of Trigger is a feature in some databases systems that, answering your question, creates some type of cursor with the data you use on the insert command so you can handle it inside that trigger.

Comment: "Insert value into a view, which is impossible." oh, ye of little faith. Depends entirely on the kind of view. After all, a view is just a stored query

Answer (score 4):

> The guy there was trying to insert values into a view... which is
>   impossible of course.

This isn't true. A view can be inserted into when it meets t[he rules for updatable views](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180800.aspx) and the values can be unambiguously mapped to inserts on a single table.

> Doesn't the inserted table contain data that has only actually been
>   inserted somewhere?

For an `AFTER INSERT` trigger this is basically true. The rows in the `INSERTED` 
pseudo table reflect those that were inserted to the table. For an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger a work table is created independently to hold the data.

Looking at an example

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.Foo
AS
SELECT CAST('A' AS varchar(8000)) AS X

GO 
CREATE TRIGGER TR 
ON Foo
INSTEAD OF INSERT AS 
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM inserted
```

And then trying

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON;
insert into  dbo.Foo
SELECT TOP 1000 REPLICATE('A',8000)
FROM master..spt_values v1;
```

The execution plan indicates that it inserts to a clustered index on `Foo`

[image]

There is of course no clustered index on `Foo` created above. The `inserted` table is a worktable in `tempdb`.

The statistics IO results show

> Table '**Worktable**'. Scan count 0, logical reads 7619, physical reads 0,
>   read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob
>   read-ahead reads 0. Table 'spt_values'. Scan count 1, logical reads 8,
>   physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob
>   physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>
> (1 row(s) affected) Table '**Worktable**'. Scan count 1, logical reads
>   1002, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob
>   physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>
> (1000 row(s) affected)

The first reference is for the insert into it, the second for the `SELECT` in the trigger itself

Comment: ok buy my point was... for the inserted table... why if it doesn't actually insert anything, then why does the inserted table have values in it?

Comment: @john - When you insert into a view with an instead of trigger the values get inserted into a worktable with the same schema as the view. For you to then do what you want with in the trigger.

Comment: oh so it means that I can get an insertion error but still the values that i was trying to insert would get into the "inserted" table?

Comment: Not if the insertion error was when adding the values to the worktable. e.g. the following would fail `insert into  dbo.Foo
SELECT TOP 1000 REPLICATE(CAST('A' AS varchar(MAX)),9000)
FROM master..spt_values v1` because a 9000 character string can't fit into `varchar(8000)`. If the insertion error was from code in the trigger itself then that doesn't start running until the worktable is fully populated.

Comment: so how can i distinguish for which errors they will be in the inserted table?

Comment: yea i got this part ... but i don't get the error part... :D

Comment: @john - Well if there's an error creating the `INSERTED` worktable then your trigger won't ever get fired. If there's an error from code inside your trigger that happens to perform an insert then the error message will tell you that the error happened inside `Procedure <YourTriggerName>`